# Mathematica not converting $A A$ to $A^2$

Tags: factorization

I'm trying to factor a large polynomial $p$ in Mathematica. When running $\text{Factor}[p]$, however, one of the factors is $-Aq + A^2 Aq + 2 A q - 2 A Aq^2 q - Aq q^2 + A^2 Aq q^2$. This is clearly divisible by $Aq$, but I can't seem to get Mathematica to recognize this regardless of what command I use, and suspect that this is because it does not treat $A^2Aq$ as $A^3q$, which I believe precludes it from factoring further as well.

For now I can do this manually and this shouldn't be too much a problem, except that I will soon have to factor even larger polynomials and will not be able to finish the computation by hand.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Note that `Aq` is different from `A q`.  Have missed out a space somewhere?

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 4):

Works fine if you enter it with correct syntax:

```
-A q + A^2 A q + 2 A q - 2 A A q^2 q - A q q^2 + A^2 A q q^2
```

> A q + A^3 q - A q^3 - 2 A^2 q^3 + A^3 q^3